# React properties not bubbling down

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component(parent) that has as state another react component(child) 
The parent passes down is't state as props to the child.
But if I do setState on the passed down property, it does not update in the child.How do I make such that a change in state is reflected in the child?
See code:

```
        class Child extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)    
            }

            render() {
                return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.x}
                </div>
                )
            }
        }

        class Parent extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)

                this.state = {x: 1, intervalID: 0, currentScreen: <Child x={0} />}
            }

            componentDidMount() {
                let self = this
                let intervalID = setInterval(function() {
                    self.setState({x: self.state.x+1})
                }, 1000)
                self.setState({intervalID: intervalID, currentScreen: <Child x={self.state.x} />})
            }

            render() {

                return (
                <div>
                    {this.state.currentScreen}
                </div>
                )
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.props.x}
        </div>
        )
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {x: 1, intervalID: 0, currentScreen: <Child x={0} />}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
            const x = this.state.x + 1;
            this.setState({
                x: x,
                currentScreen: <Child x={x} />
            });
        }, 1000)
        this.setState({intervalID: intervalID, currentScreen: <Child x={this.state.x} />})
    }

    render() {

        return (
        <div>
            {this.state.currentScreen}
        </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child component is not updating because for the lifecycle of parent component `componentDidMount` is only called once when it is being mounted.

If you need to update your state on regular interval you can do something like :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.x}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { x: 1, intervalID: 0 }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let self = this
    let intervalID = setInterval(function () {
      self.setState({ x: self.state.x + 1 })
    }, 1000)
    self.setState({ intervalID: intervalID })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Child x={this.state.x}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

for your case, just so when `setState` is done, it will call render again and it will pass the latest value of x to the child component.

You can check out live working example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mbcvt7)

Comment: Yes, i know doing <Child x={this.state.x}/> in the parents' render method works.The problem is when I do {this.state.currentScreen}.I want to do it like that because I have multiple screens and I hate using react router.This was just a sample of the problem I was facing, not the real code.

Comment: multiple screen as in multiple pages in your application ? In that case anyway when you load different page current component will be unmounted so any of these ways wont work.

Comment: for this you can use `redux` in which you can have action dispatched after 1 sec and after that the pro will update.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practise to maintain JSX in the state. Move all your JSX into the `render()` and use state variables to manage the state as shown below (For brevity only the **Parent** component code is shown).

Further instead of doing `let self=this` use the arrow function for clarity.

Note that you need to use the [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) when setting the state if your new state depends on the previous state. This is because React does batch updates for state. More information can be found in the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { x: 1 }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => {
        return { x: prevState.x + 1 };
      });
    },3000)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Child x={this.state.x} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Above function will update the value of `x` every 3 seconds. Below is a working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/2677zoo4p